# Angular - Why does service gets reset?

Tags: angular

I'm playing around with dependency injection. I made a simple demo (see below). I can update the service via events and show the changes via interpolation binding. I can also go to the sub route and see the current content of the service.

BUT if I go back to the root path the components are recreated and also the service and I loose all my data. Why is that so?

AppModule:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];

const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,HomeComponent,
    ParentComponent,Child1Component,Child2Component,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    DashboardModule
  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Service:

```
export default class DataService {
    private data: string;  
    public dataChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    public updateData(value: string) {
        this.data = value;
        this.dataChanged.emit(this.data);
    }

    public getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

In my ParentComponent I update the data in the service:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  public data: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.dataChanged.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.data = data;
      });    
    this.dataService.updateData("Initial Value (service from module level)");
  }

  updateService() {
    this.dataService.updateData(this.data + " Global ");
  }
}
```

Link from Dashboard component back to root path:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>
```

Comment: please make plunker of this

Answer (score 0):

I could not see any issue in your logic but suspecting the update change in triggered on loading the component, which is resetting the data.
Kindly check once.